# Unconditional variance of approximately simple oscillator

Tags: stochastic-processes

I am considering the Ornstein-Uhlenbeck like system
$$ dx_t = -\sinh(x_t) dt + \cosh(x_t) \sqrt{1 + 2\sinh(x_t)} dW_t $$
and wish to compute the unconditional mean $E[ x_t sinh(x_t)]$ amongst other things. Any suggestions?